# setHours() Error when Creating a Google Calendar Event from Imported Date Coming From Spreadsheet - Apps Script

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I have a form that requests an event title and start time from a user. Then inserts the information into a Google Spreadsheet. I wrote a script that imports this information into Google Calendar. However, I want every entered event to have an end time 2 hours later than the start time. Is there an easy way to do this? Here is what I have so far.

```
var title = column[3];
var startDate = column[5];        // 5th column in spreadsheet "Start Date and Time"

cal1.createEvent(title, new Date(startDate), new Date(startDate.setHours(startDate.getHours() + 2));
```

I am getting the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot find function sethours in object Fri Feb 27 2015 08:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST
```

Comment: It looks fine, have you tried to generate those dates in different variable so it would be easier to find the mistake.  Also in the error it says "sethours" (not capital H)  in your code it says setHours, is there any other place in your code where you are using this function?

Comment: your prob is your endtime is not a date type , I think. Can you show us  your startDate ?

Answer (score 0):

The value being returned from your spreadsheet for `startDate` is not being coerced into a date type.  You'll need to use `new Date()` on it to make it a date:

```
var startDate = column[5];        // 5th column in spreadsheet "Start Date and Time"
startDate = new Date(startDate);
```

Here is a test function that I ran, with some changes to the code:

```
function testIt() {

  var title = column[3];
  var startDate = column[5];        // 5th column in spreadsheet "Start Date and Time"

  startDate = new Date(startDate);
  var startHr = startDate.getHours();

  var eventEndTime = new Date(startDate);
  eventEndTime.setHours(startHr + 2);

  cal1.createEvent(title, startDate, eventEndTime);
};
```